# How to close ResearchKit Modal view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, researchkit

I am using SwiftUI to program a research kit app for personal use and I was wondering how to interact with Modal View opened Research Kit survey task.

I am using this code at the moment to open the view:

```
struct SurveyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

typealias UIViewControllerType = ORKTaskViewController

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ORKTaskViewController {

    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask, taskRun: nil)
    taskViewController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.64, green:0.15, blue:0.11, alpha:1.00)
    return taskViewController

}

func updateUIViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, context: Context) {
    }

}
```

I am using a button to call it, however I can't make it close with the cancel or done button in research kit as I am in the dark as to where I should implement the `didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason`.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it using Coordinators. If anyone is interested, here is the code.

```
struct SurveyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}


typealias UIViewControllerType = ORKTaskViewController

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ORKTaskViewController {

    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: SurveyTask, taskRun: nil)
    taskViewController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.64, green:0.15, blue:0.11, alpha:1.00)
    taskViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    return taskViewController

}

func updateUIViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, context: Context) {

    }

class Coordinator: NSObject, ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {
    func taskViewController(_ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWith reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: Error?) {
        taskViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried creating the ORKInstructionStep and ORKOrderedTask in the makeUIViewController and then putting the SurveyView into a SwiftUI VStack but the code is crashing. What should I do to get SurveyView() to work in a SwiftUI view?